# ODI 12.1.3 couldn't use Non-ordered joins with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, outer-join, oracle-data-integrator

Using ODI 12.1.3, Microsoft SQL Server

In mapping I used `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but when I run mapping I got an error and a warning.

Error:

> Non-ordered outer joins are not supported in technology Microsoft SQL Server.

Warning:

> Non-ordered joins are not supported in technology Microsoft SQL Server.

When I tried to change data handling in SQL Server from (Topology > Physical Architecture > Technologies)

I marked for "Not Ordered" in Join Support.

Then from SQL tab under Definition. I changed Not ordered as below data

```
 Outer Keyword:          +
 Outer Location:         Outer Side
 Clause Location:        After Column for Join Only
```

After change data handling still get an error "Incorrect Syntax"

Comment: Hi did you find the answer ?

Comment: I solved it
you can use option "ANSI SQL" in database technology